# Is there a word for when you use an abstract noun in a concrete sense?

Tags: terminology, figures-of-speech

In *The Crucible*, Reverend Hale says that his books are "weighted with authority". Here authority is used as if it's a concrete noun so I was wondering if there is a technical term for when you use an abstract noun as if it's a concrete noun.

Comment: Why do you think this is a concrete noun? Does the phrase “heavy with sorrow” make sorrow a concrete noun?

Comment: @Xanne - Concrete is a famously heavy material. Seriously though, isn't "heavy with sorrow" exactly the same type of construction as the OP's example such that they probably have the same question about both phrases?

Comment: Yes; the point is that the metaphor doesn’t make the noun concrete.

Comment: What makes you think that authority is concrete in this sentence? A concrete noun can be perceived through one of the 5 senses in an objective way - authority is not concrete, the books are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that in this metaphor, ***books weighted with authority***, it is not the noun *authority* that becomes concrete; it is the past participle *weighted* that becomes abstract, the context simply points to that.

And though a ***metaphor*** does many things, it also includes this phenomenon: taking a concrete word and shifting its meaning to something abstract, like a feeling, a concept, etc. [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=metaphor%20meaning&sxsrf=AOaemvL-wREhKqMC0lIqhFkKWcWFPGm7Hg%3A1634894335801&ei=_4FyYZKyMIGC8gK4_IDQBw&oq=metaphor%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIABCABBAKOgQIABANOgcIIxCwAhAnOgcIIxCxAhAnSgQIQRgAUIWXDljuoQ5gwq8OaAJwAngAgAFniAGTBZIBAzcuMZgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) defines metaphor as:

> a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is ***not literally applicable***.

So although a concrete word is not literally applicable to an abstract one, you can do this in a metaphor to obtain new meanings and literary effect:

> - His ***fear*** consumed him ***like a hungry beast consumes its prey***. (there is no real beast, nor a real prey involved: it is a figure of speech - a metaphor)

Using concrete language can help understand better the abstract meaning we are trying to convey (I recommend [this article](https://www.albert.io/blog/concrete-and-abstract-nouns/)), but the meaning remains abstract nevertheless.