Remember this CocaCola tagline?
What rhetorical device is being used in the CocaCola tagline 'Open Happiness'?

How about this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577223/is-there-a-word-for-when-you-use-an-abstract-noun-in-a-concrete-sense ?

You should explain the meaning and context in which it's used in advertisements etc. Open has a lot of meanings, and it's not even clear if it's an adjective or verb here: it could be an instruction (imperative verb), a description of a type of happiness (adjective), or other things.

From the comment gallery, it's a metaphor.

Happiness is like a soft drink, you have to open the bottle or can. A
simple metaphor. - Lambie


Yes, it's a metaphor because the prototypical sense of 'open' involves a physical change (though Etymon says the adjective is older ... but still the physical state was involved). 'Open happiness' obviously refers to the physical, but also to the 'get hold of' some happiness broadening. –
Edwin Ashworth


I think what makes the phrase 'catchy' is the unexpected use of an abstract noun ("happiness") in a context that would normally call for a concrete noun (i.e., as the direct object of "open"). So, if there were a name for this device, it would relate abstract to concrete in the same way that 'personification' relates inanimate to human. Something like "concretification" (obviously not that, specifically, though!)? –
Quack E. Duck

Also this related question Is there a word for when you use an abstract noun in a concrete sense? [closed]
